# What's the right way to drop trailing zeros of a BigDecimal in Scala?

Tags: scala, tostring, bigdecimal

`scala.math.BigDecimal.toString` can return something like "0.888200000". What can be the best I can do if I want "0.8882" instead? `java.math.BigDecimal` has `stripTrailingZeros()` method for this, but Scala's BigDecimal seems lacking it. Is using `scala.math.BigDecimal.underlying` to get the underlying `java.math.BigDecimal` the best way to go or is there a better way in Scala?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about an implicit def if you want access to all the Java methods but don't want to type the `underlying`?

```
val b = math.BigDecimal("0.888200000")
implicit def bigDecimalToJavaBigDecimal(b: math.BigDecimal) = b.underlying

scala> b.stripTrailingZeros
res1: java.math.BigDecimal = 0.8882
```

You get a Java `BigDecimal` back, but that's OK because there's already an `implicit def` back to the Scala version which you get when you import `math.BigDecimal`, called `javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal`.

Comment: What I ask about is not about "don't want to type" but about performance and type/reference safety: I am curios about any inobvious problems such an approach can lead to. Though, as nobody suggests anything better and everyone is upvoting this answer, I will consder that the answer is "yes, using `.underlying` is ok and there is no better way to drop trailing zeros" and probably follow the advice to use the implicit.

Comment: In practice you (hopefully) won't be stripping the zeros in multiple places in your code, so I'd just use `b.underlying.stripTrailingZeros` rather than going to the trouble of creating this implicit method. There is no performance hit in using `underlying` since if you look at the source it just returns a field on the object.

Comment: In practice I've just appended `.stripTrailingZeros` to `rs.getBigDecimal(1)` to strip the zeros right at the entrance :-)

Comment: @Ivan Better to do `stripTrailingZeros` before inserting into database. That's the real entrance :-)